# Convert HTML form with action to React form submit with logic

Tags: html, reactjs

Folks, I think I'm either missing something here or *I don't know what I don't know*.

What I have is:

```
<form action="/orders/populate" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="name" id="name"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="rating" id="rating"/>
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Rate Now" />
</form>
```

What I want to do is:

```
Class myComponent extends React.PureComponent {
    handleSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // don't know if this is necessary
      sendAnalytics();
      // then form submit
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <form action="/orders/populate" method="post" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
              <input type="hidden" name="name" id="name"/>
              <input type="hidden" name="rating" id="rating"/>
              <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Rate Now" />
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

Don't know what has to be done here. Can someone point out an example similar to this? Or perhaps give me a sample code below?

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

```
Class myComponent extends React.PureComponent {

this.state = {
 name: ''  // initial value for name 
 rating: '' // initial value for rating
}

handleInput = e => {
 this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}
handleSubmit = e => {
  const { name, rating } = this.state;
  e.preventDefault(); // yes, this is necessary otherwise it's refresh your page.
  sendAnalytics(name, rating); // api call to store in DB. to call API use axios npm package

}

render () {
    const { name, rating } = this.state;

    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text" name="name" value={name} id="name" onChange={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}/>
          <input type="text" name="rating" value={rating} id="rating" onChange={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}/>
          <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Rate Now" />
        </form>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about this, although I don't want to set each and every input value in state *(actual code has around 25 values)*  and I really don't want to have all of them in a state.

Although, I digress. I'm more concerned about `form-action-method` part. Will the above code handle it? Because your handlleInput is pretty generic, love that part.

Comment: @darth-coder if you don't want to set all the value in state then you can go with formik form. https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/overview . formik will handle all your headache. :)

Comment: This solution looks pretty good to me. The only thing I would change is remove the arrow function from the onClhange Handler. You can just write this.handleInput there.

Comment: @Gh05d then you need to manage with bind(this) if you don't use autobind-decorator module.

Comment: Are you sure? As handleSubmit is an arrow function, it should be automatically binded.

Comment: yes, I'm pretty sure  if you use arrow function then it's bind automaticaly. like this handleSubmit = event => { do code }. same for any function.

Comment: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) for handling forms in React? This will give you insights in how to use forms with react, since it handles a bit different than regular html forms

Comment: I did look at the docs initially. But got confused because at no point it speaks about form-action-submit.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem I've faced in React. You have one of three ways:

1) Use a third party React-Form library to do the job. There are several.

2) Use React-hooks (a very recent addition to React).

3) Create a generic Form class to handle this state management for you...like so:

```
export default class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      values: {}
    };
  }

  @boundMethod
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.props.submit(this.state.values);
  }

  @boundMethod
  handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    const newValues = Object.assign(
      { ...this.state.values },
      { [name]: value }
    );
    this.setState({
      values: newValues
    });
  }

  public render() {
    const { values } = this.state;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} noValidate={true}>
        <div>
          {React.Children.map(
            this.props.children,
            child => (
                {React.cloneElement(child, {
                  value: values[child.props.name],
                  onChange: this.handleChange
                })}
            )
          )}
          <div>
            <button type="submit">
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Then you will be able to use this Form class like so:

```
<Form
  submit={values => {
    /* work with values */
  }}
>
  <input type="hidden" name="name" />
  <input type="hidden" name="rating" />
</Form>;
```

**PS**: 
Keep in mind `boundMethod` Decorator is something that is not natively available but a module called 'autobind-decorator' I tend to use a lot to deal with `this` not being bound.

Comment: I'll give this a try.